# Exclude base library inclusions from Doxygen dependency graph?

Tags: c++, graph, dependencies, documentation, doxygen

I'm documenting a c++ project for college with Doxygen, and everything is correct, but the dependency graph shows like this:[image: dependency graph]

I would like that the graph doesn't show inclusions such as list, map or string, and only includes custom Classes i created for the project, but i can't find anything online or on the docs. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It's not what you asked for but [here's a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17886130).

Answer (score 6):

Since you want to exclude the stdlib container classes, you should probably add the `std::` namespace to your doxyfile:

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS = std::*
```

This will ignore all classes located in that namespace, and thus skip them in the generated diagram.

Comment: Does not work for me. STL #include files are still referenced in the dependency graph as shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17886130/1150303):

```
/** @cond */
#include <string>
// include more headers
/** @endcond */
```

Not that this solution is particularly beautiful but it seems to work.
Note, you may have to have the `@file` tag defined.