# Exclude Qt from doxygen header dependency graph

Tags: c++, qt, doxygen, static-analysis

I have a Qt-based C++ project and a Doxyfile to generate a documentation website for it. I like the include dependency graphs enabled by `INCLUDE_GRAPH` and `INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH`. Sometimes, however, they get very cluttered by all the Qt headers included. (How) can I only display my own files there?
I tried adding `EXCLUDE = /usr/include/qt`, to no avail. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987573/exclude-base-library-inclusions-from-doxygen-dependency-graph) has no answer, either.

Comment: We use EXCLUDE_PATTERNS. Try this: `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = */include/qt/*`

Comment: @V-R does not work, the Qt types are still in the include dependency graphs

Comment: Also searched around about a similar problem (glib dependency here). The only clunky work-around I found is https://stackoverflow.com/a/17886130/4545530

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit outdated but I have found the answer. Set up the `INPUT_FILTER` (under Expert/Input in `doxywizard`) to

```
sed -e "s:#include <Q.*>:// REMOVED:g"
```

This will preprocess any file that Doxygen analyses and replace all `#include <QAnything>` with comment `// REMOVED`.

Comment: Smart idea. Unfortunately it doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: @ChristophLipka it should be possible in windows by similar way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe

Comment: couldn't test it anymore, but sounds plausible, so I'm accepting the answer. thanks @Roman